# Why are the kernel of the irreducible factors of the minimal and charateristic polynomial equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

If $\varphi$ is an Endomorphism over $V$ with $\mu_\varphi=\prod^n_{i=1}p_i^{m_i}$ for some  $n,m_i$ and irreducible $p_i$ and $\chi_\varphi=\prod^n_{i=1} p_i^{c_i}$ with $c_i\geq m_i$ then $\operatorname{ker} p_i^{m_i}(\varphi)=\operatorname{ker} p_i^{c_i}(\varphi)$. Why? This statement is required to prove, that generalized eigenspaces can be optained from either the minimal polynomial or characteristical polynomial.

I get why $\operatorname{ker} p_i^{m_i}(\varphi)\subseteq\operatorname{ker} p_i^{c_i}(\varphi)$ (this directly follows from $m_i\leq c_i$). I don't get why the other direction holds though.

Comment: Consider the facts that the $\ker p_i^{m_i}(\varphi) \cap \ker p_j^{m_j}(\varphi) = \{0\}$ and that $\sum_i \dim \ker p_i^{m_i}(\varphi) = \dim(V)$. Intuitively, we cannot make any of these subspaces bigger without causing some of them to intersect.

Comment: Perhaps this is easier for you to see in a specific case of an algebraically closed field, e.g. over $\mathbb C$ we could have $m(x) = (x-2)^3(x-i)^2$ and $c(x) = (x-2)^3(x-i)^3$. Each is a product of powers of linear factors so the result you seek follows immediately. The more general case is trickier (field might not be algebraically closed nor characteristic $0$).

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen in your example, why does kernel of $(x-i)^2$ have to be equal to $(x-i)^3$? That's the part I don't get, why can't there be a vector, which is not zero yet at $(x-i)^2$ but becomes zero after applying the (x-i) transformation again?

Comment: Let $p=p_i$ and $m=m_i$. Write $\mu=p^mg$, with $g$ relatively prime with $p$. I will also write $p$ and $g$ for these polynomials evaluated at $\phi$, to write less. Then there are $a,b$ such that $ap^c+bg=1$. Take $v\in ker(p^c(\phi))$. Then $v=ap^cv+bgv=bgv$. Applying $p^m$ on both sides $p^mv=bp^mgv=b\mu v=0$. So, $ker(p^c(\phi))\subset ker(p^m(\phi))$. The other inclusion is clear.